# Which method of tomcat installation is needed in linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

Currently I need to deploy my enterprise App in Tomcat7 in linux machine. However I find two ways of tomcat installation:

1. Using apt-get install
2. Downloading the binaries

I confused, which method needs to be used for enterprise APP?
Please share your suggestions

Comment: The only benefit using the apt version is getting updates.

Comment: yes, that is advantage. However if we use apt-get, it installs the tomcat in linux official directories. Whether this cause any difficulty to deployed App? like difficulty in writing log files, accessing temp files etc

Comment: That will work, but imho I like the neccessary files placed in one location, because I can easily keep an eye on them and update them myself. I even install a single jdk along with every tomcat, so it has its own setting/version/environemt of java too.